# Editing a Question's Title

Tags: discussion, editing

On the topic of editing other people's questions.

Is it acceptable to significantly edit a question's title so that it might be found more easily?

I'm thinking of [this question](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/16404/gibbs-free-energy). The title "Gibbs Free Energy?" is vague and doesn't really summarize well the real question which is "What is an irreversible reaction?"

For whatever reason, though, it seems kind of rude to edit the title of someone else's post.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is perfectly acceptable, even encouraged to edit titles that are too vague or misleading. Titles are very important, a bad or misleading title makes it harder to find stuff and also might lead to the question being overlooked by users that could answer it.

Just edit the title and improve it, that is the right thing to do in this case.